# Serving files & handling requests with Webrick on same port

Tags: ruby, rubygems, server, file-handling, webrick

Hi I have a need to be able to receive requests from GitLab (body => JSON) as well as serve files on same port. I am trying to use Webrick for this purpose. I can do these separately.

To serve files I do:

```
server = WEBrick::HTTPServer.new(:Port => 3030, :DocumentRoot => '/')
server.start
```

To receive and process jSON I do:

```
server = WEBrick::HTTPServer.new(:Port => 3030, :DocumentRoot => '/')
server.mount_proc '/' do | req, res |
    Queue.new(req.body)
end
```

But I need this functionality combined, is there a way to do this with Webrick?

Comment: I love the answer @Anthony gave, but I wonder - why not use a framework instead? Rails, Sinatra and [Plezi](https://github.com/boazsegev/plezi) should all work faster then Webrick when used in a concurrent environment such as production - and both Sinatra and Plezi should be as easy (if not easier) to implement...

Comment: This is for the in-house CI implementation for the Big Data pipeline testing, not facing customers and we wanted it to be as light weight as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is certainly possible with Webrick or any HTTP server.  There will be two different HTTP actions depending on what the users wants to do, 1.) a GET request to serve the files or 2.) a POST request to process some JSON.

Here's a simple example to show you how to do both:

```
class Server < WEBrick::HTTPServlet::AbstractServlet
    def do_GET (request, response)
      puts "this is a get request"
    end

    def do_POST (request, response)
      puts "this is a post request who received #{request.body}"
    end
end

server = WEBrick::HTTPServer.new(:Port => 3030)

server.mount "/", Server

trap("INT") {
    server.shutdown
}

server.start
```

Once that is running you can test this by doing the following in a separate terminal window:

```
curl localhost:3030
```

output:

```
this is a get request
localhost - - [23/Apr/2015:06:39:20 EDT] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 0
- -> /
```

To test the POST request:

```
curl -d "{\"json\":\"payload\"}" localhost:3030
```

output:

```
this is a post request who received {"json":"payload"}
localhost - - [23/Apr/2015:06:40:07 EDT] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 0
- -> /
```

Comment: Thank you, I solved it myself before your answer actually, but I find your answer much more elegantly implemented. Thank you one more time.

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned the purpose was a light code-base, here's a light, fast script using the [Plezi framework](https://github.com/boazsegev/plezi)...

This will allow for easier testing, I think (but I'm biased). Also, Plezi is faster on my machine then Webrick (although it's a pure ruby framework, no rack or 'c' extensions involved).

```
require 'plezi'

class MyController
    def index
        # parsed JSON is acceible via the params Hash i.e. params[:foo]
        # raw JSON request is acceible via request[:body]
        # returned response can be set by returning a string...
        "The request's params (parsed):\n#{params}\n\nThe raw body:\n#{request[:body]}"
    end
end

# start to listen and set the root path for serving files.
listen root: './'

# set a catch-all route so that MyController#index is always called.
route '*', MyController
```

(if you're running the script from the terminal, remember to exit `irb` using the `exit` command - this will activate the web server)